# Converting my json index

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, ruby-on-rails-3

I am trying to convert the following json index from the following style

```
[{"event":{"title":"test"}},{"event":{"title":"test2"}}]
```

but instead of having it this way i am wondering if its possible to create the index json action as the following json structure

```
{"event": [ { "title":"test"},{ "title":"test2" }] }
```

I can generate the first style by the following code

```
respond_with @events.as_json(:root => true, :only => [:title])
```

But not sure how to have rails to generate json index structure has the second format

Comment: The main reason, is because, the smartphone android application, doesn't read properly the json. We are using the android provided on this page http://lucatironi.github.com/tutorial/2012/10/16/ruby_rails_android_app_authentication_devise_tutorial_part_two/ and unfortunotly, it doesn't read properly because its not the proper format

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you'll have to build the json yourself, ie:

```
render :json, {event: @events.map {|e| {title: e.title}}}.to_json
```

If it gets too complex, you probably should use [RABL](https://github.com/nesquena/rabl) (see the railscast [here](http://railscasts.com/episodes/322-rabl))

Comment: `as_json` returns a Hash so this could just be: `{event: @events.as_json(root: false, only: [:title])}`. OP could also use ActiveModelSerializers for even more control. It's a great library.